# How to default select the first item in multiple select field in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have made a Stackblitz application where I am using a select box , with multiple selection . I want to default select the first item always , but I am unable to achieve it .

I am using selected ="i==0" but that doesnt help .

```
<select multiple class="custom-select" formControlName="cityName">
              <option *ngFor="let city of City ;let i= index;" [ngValue]="city" [selected]="i==0" (change)="changeCity($event)">{{city}}</option>
            </select>
```

Here's the stackblitz link -

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-select-dropdown-reactive-forms?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Can anyone please help me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```js
registrationForm = this.fb.group({
    cityName: [[this.City[0]], [Validators.required]]
});
```

The select is multiple, so in order to pre-select some options, you need to set the form value with an array. In this array, you just push the first city: `this.City[0]`

If you're getting datas from a service, then you could do like this :

```js
registrationForm: FormGroup;
cities = City[] = [];

constructor(private myService: MyService) {
  registrationForm = this.fb.group({
    cityName: [[], [Validators.required]]
  });

  this.myService.getCities().subscribe(cities => {
    this.cities = cities;
    this.registrationForm.get('cityName').patchValue([].concat(cities[0]))
  });
}
```

In this example, `getCities()` must return an `Observable<City[]>` like an Http request, or something like `of(['Florida', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Michigan', 'New York'])`

Comment: Great thank you . It worked  . if i can ask what should i do if the City array gets populated from a service later in the component ?

Comment: @AnandSrivastava I've edited my post please check

Comment: Wow , that worked . Need to study about patchValue now . Thank you so much . You made my life easier .

Comment: Super ! You can find some informations here -> https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#updating-parts-of-the-data-model